# VS2008: Multiple build configs with defines don't work as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, conditional-compilation, buildconfiguration

I have a base library to maintain in multiple versions. I do a SVN switch whenever I need to work on another version.

I don't have multiple versions of my test application solution, so I thought that for different versions I could do multiple solution / project configurations that define symbols for the version to be able to have version-specific code in my test.

Currently I have the following build configurations in the test application solution: Debug, Release, DebugV10, ReleaseV10, DebugV15, ReleaseV15. In the *V10 and *V15 configs, I created and selected corresponding *V10 and *V15 PROJECT configurations for the two projects that have version-specific test code (not for all projects, most run normal Debug / Release configuration in the solution -Vx configuration).

In those project configurations I entered the corresponding conditional compilation symbols (VERSION10 and VERSION15).

Now in my code in the project I go like

```
#if VERSION10
  // do v1.0 stuff
#elif VERSION15
  // do v1.5 stuff
#else
  // do trunk stuff
#endif
```

But apparently VS doesn't recognize the symbols. Even a simple #if DEBUG does not work anymore, allthoug define DERBUG constant is checked in all Debug* project configurations.

Is this a known thing? What can I do about it?

Comment: How do you define the symbols? If it is just defined (without any value), shouldn't you use **#if defined**? Also, sometimes the symbol is recognized correctly, but not visualized correctly by VS, i.e not grayed out correctly.

Comment: I defined the symbols on the Project properties "Build" - tab in the field for conditional compilation symbols. And it's not only visualization, the conditional code is in fact not compiled in ANY configuration, not even normal #if DEBUG code in the normal, unmodified debug build configuration (that was only used to copy the settings from).

Comment: btw: **#if defined** is not a valid directive in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept that you describe sounds fine.

That is, the code uses:

```
#if VERSION10 ... #endif
```

and the Project configuration defines `VERSION10`

and a Solution configuration is set up that is set to use the above Project configuration.

As long as these are all set up correctly, I'd expect it to work.

The fact that you say even #if DEBUG isn't working as expected suggests that something is very broken.

I'd suggest you try the simplest possible case, to ensure you undersatand how to set it up: Create a new minimal "hello world" application that just has simple code that allows you to tell apart the versions:

```
#if VERSION1
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from version 1");
#else
  Console.WriteLine("Hello from version 2");
#endif
```

Then create project configurations ("Debug Version 1", "Debug version 2") and see if you can set them up (one with VERSION1 defined, one without) to get the two outputs when built.

Then add Solution configurations that use the above Project configurations, and build them to check that they print the right things when executed.

Once you've done this you should have a working system (an understanding of how these elements relate to each other) that you can apply back to your more complex project. To apply them back, I suggest deleting most of the project/solution configurations and then rebuilding them from scratch now that you are sure you know what to do - often rebuilding these things from first principles works out better than trying to tweak an existing 'broken' setup back into life.

Comment: Something unknown really was wrong. I removed all configs and set them up again and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional compilation in C# is different from C and C++.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) for info on the `ConditionalAttribute` class.

For example:

```
doDebugOutput();    // unconditionally call the optional code

Conditional["DEBUG"]
void DoDebugOutput()
{
  // do expensive debug-only output here
}
```